# DataTables - invalid SORT results when using CHROME

Tags: javascript, sorting, datatable, datatables

**Hi,**

I was working with datatables and noticed a very strange behavior on Chrome when using custom sort functions.

**This are my findings:**

- when working with small lists (less than ~10) custom sorts work well on chrome and in Firefox
- when working with slight bigger tables (still small, around 30 entries) Firefox still returns valid sort results, but Chrome fails to do this.

I made a fiddle where you can see the behavior. Inside you l'll see two tables which are same just have different data sizes, first one small - everything works there be it Chrome or Firefox.

The second one is bigger and chrome fails to sort it.

**Fiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/ogoossens/d35cb4eh/3/

**Parts of my code**

**Custom sort functions:**

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort["customSort-desc"] = function (x, y) {
    return formatPrice(x) < formatPrice(y);
};
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort["customSort-asc"] = function (x, y) {
    return formatPrice(x) > formatPrice(y);
};
```

**How I cleanup the Number Format**

```
function formatPrice(unformattedPrice) {

    // For debugging purposes
    let returnValue = unformattedPrice;

    // Here I check if there is "-" if so teh price shall be considered as 0
    if (unformattedPrice == "-") {
        returnValue = 0;
    } else {

        // If not lets get rid of EVERYTHING except the numbers
        returnValue = returnValue.replace(" ","");
        returnValue = returnValue.replace("$","");
    }

    // Lets make sure itll be considered float
    returnValue = parseFloat(returnValue);

    return returnValue;
}
```

**How I define my tables:**

```
    $('#example-ok').DataTable({
    "paging": false,
    "searching": false,
    "info": false,
    order: [],
    "columns": [
        {
            "bSortable": true,
            "sType": "customSort"
        },
    ]
});
```

Try to open the full Fiddle in Firefox and Chrome and tell me if its only me where the second table wont sort.

**Thank you**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the array to sort has equal values, when you have equal values you should use something like:

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort["customSort-desc"] = function (x, y) {
        if(formatPrice(x) == formatPrice(y)){
        return 0;
        }    
        if(formatPrice(x) < formatPrice(y)){
        return 1
        }
        if(formatPrice(x) > formatPrice(y)){
        return -1
        }

    };
```

Full example here: https://jsfiddle.net/15qdx4g9/1/

It's the same behavior using `.sort()`. To be honest, I don't know why the difference between Chrome and Firefox, I guess it's because different implementations of `.sort()`

Comment: Wow! So same values were the main issue and somehow Firefox was able to ignore that okay! :-) Thank you very much this solved my issue.